# Signing message SOAP with WSO2 EI

Tags: sign, ws-security, wso2-esb

I would like to ask for help, as you can electronically sign the SOAP message content in WSO2 EI, I really do not find much information. Can you guide me about it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got ir right, but you can sign SOAP messages using rampart in wso2. You have to define your security policy and add it to the enpoint mediator.

Example:

```
 <send>
            <endpoint name="secure">
                <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SecureStockQuoteService">
                    <enableSec policy="sec_policy"/>
                    <enableAddressing/>
                </address>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
```

You can find further information here.

[Signing messages](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Sample+100%3A+Using+WS-Security+for+Outgoing+Messages)

[Rampart](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/rampartconfig-guide.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will review the documentation related to rampart.